# Comparing a virtual child's filters to parent table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, parent-child

I haven't a clue as to how to do this. I'm using Access 2007, and coding in VBA and SQL.

Table A has Data, accounts and amounts. Users can use form B to access subsets of the data in A, say, all the rows with amounts between $50 and $100.

When the user is looking at a row, I need to know if there are any other rows with the same account that are excluded from their view. In other words, I need to know if there are rows visible in the parent that aren't visible in the child.

I think a solution is to determine what filters are active on their view, and then I can use dcount to compare. I don't know how to get at the filters that are active in their view, though. And there may be an easier way - I am out of my depth here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that TableA has a primary key ID. Using the current event for the FormB:

```
 Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset

 dAmt = Me.Amount
 sAcc = Me.Account 

 ''Get a list of visible IDs
 With Me.RecordsetClone
    .MoveFirst

     Do While Not .EOF
         If !Amount=dAmt And !Account=sAcc Then
            sIDs = sIDs & "," & .ID
         End If
         .MoveNext
     Loop
 End with

 ''Other IDs
 sSQL = "SELECT * FROM TableA "
      & "WHERE Amount = " & dAmt _
      & "Account = '" & sAcc _
      & "' ID Not In (" & Mid(sIDs,2) & ")"

 CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef("NewQ",sSQL")
 Docmd.OpenQuery NewQ
```

The above is untested, and as it stands, will only run once, if it runs at all, because a new query is created, rather than an existing query being edited.

Comment: Thanks Remou. I ended up going another direction (just made the button visible always, and let the user decide if they want to see more), but this makes sense, and if I need to do this at another point, I have a jumping off point now.